# Xerox Phaser on Mac OS X El Capitan: how to reduce print density?

Tags: macos, mac, printing, printer

I recently acquired a used Xerox Phaser 6180mfp color printer. I have it attached over a network link to my Mac OS X El Capitan laptop. It operates well, except that pictures printed from Preview and iPhoto are oversaturated.  I can find no parameters in the print driver or printer console to control print darkness/lightness or density.  I have consulted both the User Manual and the Service Manual for the printer and done numerous on-line searches without any useful answers.

Is there a way to tell the printer or the system to lighten up the prints?

Comment: Check for updated drivers at [Phaser 6180MFP Support & Drivers](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-6180mfp/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=macosx1011). The [Xerox Customer Support Forum](http://forum.support.xerox.com/) is a good place to ask this question.

Comment: Color calibration is pretty much an entire topic of its own & getting a fully calibrated workflow is not cheap. Entry level colorimeters [they start around $100] don't include print in the workflow, so you'd need to go up a level. The [Spyder](http://spyder.datacolor.com/display-calibration/) is one solution, but note how pricey it gets to include Printer calibration :/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question that was answered anywhere I could find.  I appreciated @creidhne's pointer to the [Xerox Customer Support Forum](http://forum.support.xerox.com/). That proved to have some useful information, but nothing about color adjustments.  What I was looking for was not a fully calibrated, colorimeter-based adjustment, or adjustments for application print drivers, but something that would cover basic printing from preview and other non-photographic apps.  What I discovered is that Mac OS has the ability to adjust printer defaults using the CUPS browser interface.

This will expose the printer driver settings for any printer you have configured.

1. Use your browser to go to `http://127.0.0.1:631/`
2. Then the `Printers` button will take you to a list or printers
3. Choose the one you want to change parameters for and click on it
4. Use the pull-downs to choose `Maintenance` and `Set Default Options`
5. The Default Options page has all manner of defaults you can set.  One group of defaults for the 6190mfp was `Color Adjustment`

Choosing that link put me at a place where I could reduce the in-printer Gamma, RGB correction method, Color Temperature, and color profile--all pull-down driven choices.  A little experimenting got me good results with the following:

- RGB Correction Method: `Saturation` (from none)
- Profile: `Adobe 1998` (from sRGB)
- Gamma = `1.4` (from 1.8)
- Color Temperature = `6500 (D65)`  (no change)

As an aside, I discovered all then after installing a duplex unit in the printer.  There are other defaults on the page to set 2-sided printing on as a default and I discovered the Color Adjustment settings while doing that.